# How can one iterate over the entries in an OpenMDAO object

Tags: openmdao

The Problem object in OpenMDAO is programmed to behave like a dictionary of all the Problem variables declared in the objects and what-not. Now I can iterate over normal dictionaries with for loops like:

```
for key,value in my_dict.iteritems():
    do_something(key,value)
```

Could something like this be done with OpenMDAO problems?

I have a bunch of helpful utilities for working with dictionaries. I would like to use those to work with OpenMDAO problems as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do, but it sounds like you want to iterate over all variables in the model? One way you could do that is to iterate over `prob.root.unknowns`, which is the vector that contains all the connected variables in the top `System` of your model. It is recursive in the sense that it includes connections that are specified in sub-systems. However, it doesn't include anything that isn't relevant for data-passing, so any `Component` inputs that aren't at least hooked up to an `IndepVarComp` won't show up in it.

Comment: Hi Kenneth Thanks for the help once again!

Comment: Looping over everything in the problem is helpful for building up a work flow. I have a bunch of code that checks connects, derivatives and now the actual values. I add in components one-by-one and I can confirm with every change, everything is working. So that is why I want to iterate over all the variables...

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't really like a dictionary, we just define the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods on it as a convenience for the user ([see code](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/e114404cd36c3c409252562c2d344aa3e1db8390/openmdao/core/problem.py#L102)). If you want to access the underlying dict-like object you can access `prob.root.unknowns`
instead. This is still not actually a dictionary, but a [VecWrapper](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/e114404cd36c3c409252562c2d344aa3e1db8390/openmdao/core/vec_wrapper.py#L405) instance, but it is dict-like and has the the necessary methods to be used like one in a duck-typing sense.

Comment: Thanks Justin! I liked your answer just as much as Kenneth's but I can only give one check...